# select count doesn't count

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select, count

I try to build a variable that integrates some other variable.

one of that will be the number of an auto-increment-field where later on an insert-query will happens.

I tried to use:

```
$get_num = $db/*=>mysqli*/->query("SELECT COUNT (*) auto_increment_column FROM table1");  
            $num = $query->fetch_assoc($get_num);
            $end = $num + 1;
```

I don't have any update/insert query before that so I can't use

```
$end = $db->insert_id;
```

that's why i thought i can just count the numbers of the auto_increment rows and have my last variable that is necessary to build my new variable.

for a reason this wonT count the entries and outputs 0. i dont understand why this happens.

i really would appreciate if there is someone who could tell me what am i doing wrong. thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

For everyone who likes to know about what's the goal:

I like to create a specific name or id for a file that later on will be created by the input of the fields from the insert query. I like to have  an unique key. this key consists of an user_id and a timestamp. at the end of this generated variable it should be placed the auto_increment nr. of the query that will be placed in the table. so the problem is, that I create an variable before the insert query happens so that this variable will be part of the insert query like:

```
$get_num = $db->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tableA");  
$num = $query->fetch_assoc();
$end = $num + 1;

$file_id = $id .".". time() .".". $end;

$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO tableA ( file_id, a, b, c) VALUES('".$file_id."','".$a."','".$b."','".c."')");{
```

hope now, it will be clear what I like to approach.

Comment: Why can't you just do your insert and check insert_id after it? Do you really need to know the id of the row _before_ the row is inserted?

Comment: because i like to generate a variable that can't exist twice and this variable i'm looking for should be an element of the insert-query. the other variables in that new variable are generated by time() or specific id. for my own i like to see in that output of this new variable some keys like $id-$unix-timestamp-$auto_increment_nr. for that reason i like to have that. i would like to save my own first to generate an insert and after that doing an update.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Whatever it is, don't re-invent the wheel. If you need an auto-incrementing id in MySQL use AUTO INCREMENT. If you need it in PHP use something like http://uk.php.net/uniqid but this will NOT be unique across your app, just within your request.

Comment: i already updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need an auto-incrementing column in MySQL then you should use [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html). It implements it all for you and avoids race conditions. The manual way you are trying to implement it has a couple of flaws, namely

- If two scripts are trying to insert concurrently they might both get the same COUNT (say 10) and hence both try to insert with ID 11. One will then fail (or else you will have duplicates!)
- If you add 10 items but then delete item 1, the COUNT will return 9 but id 10 will already exist.